# Pointing GoDaddy DNS to GitHub page uses http over https

Tags: ssl, https, dns, ssl-certificate, github-pages

I have my DNS settings as shown in the image
[DNS Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qk96.png) along with an additional CNAME with host www and value as my GitHub page. Next I setup a CNAME entry in my GitHub page with an apex entry to my domain. The issue I face is that whenever I visit my domain with an **https** protocol, it shows a warning that the connection is not secure. I get the following in Chrome:

> NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

How do I fix this? I have both https and http access for my domain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Please see answer below by Arturo Herrero: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50203412/462015

GitHub pages does not support HTTPS for custom domains.

The only work around for doing so is to use an SSL provider as the middle man, such as [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/). However, this would involve pointing your DNS name servers at Cloudflare's, which takes some time and complicates things.

If you want HTTPS support using GitHub pages you'll have to use GitHub's provided URL instead of your custom domain.

Another great option for static sites if you want custom domain name HTTPS is Amazon Web Services. You could set up an S3 bucket for your static website, configure CloudFront to distribute the static content, point your domain name at the CloudFront distribution, and use a free SSL certificate from Amazon's cert manager. This option comes out to less than $1/Month with a low-traffic website. A great in depth tutorial for that would be [here](https://blog.webinista.com/2016/02/enable-https-cloudfront-certificate-manager-s3/index.html).

I hope this answered your question! GitHub pages is a great hosting option, and it's not the end of the world if you decide to forget about HTTPS.

Comment: I am using Cloudflare but I wanted to know if I could do this without. Since all other posts regarding the same were very old, I was hoping things would've changed by now. Thanks for your answer regardless.

Comment: No problem. I have gone that route as well and couldn't get it to work properly, so I resolved to simply using GitHub's provided HTTPS url. I highly recommend you follow the guide I posted on S3, as that's now what I use for static sites and I think it's great once you get it down. My costs last month for one website was about $0.65.

Answer (score 23):

**UPDATE: Github introduced custom domain support for HTTPS on May 1, 2018.**

If you are using GoDaddy and want to upgrade to HTTPS, do the following:

1. Go to DNS settings for your site in your GoDaddy account.
2. Remove all existing A records.
3. Open a terminal and do `dig +noall +answer <YOUR-USERNAME>.github.io`. You should see a table listing 4 slightly different IP addresses: [image]
4. On GoDaddy, create 4 new A records, each one pointing to one of the IPs. For *host* use `@` and set the TTL to a low user-defined value (if you are in a hurry).
5. Go to your page repository settings on Github, and *[clear the custom domain name and save](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-or-removing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/)*. Wait a while (minutes).
6. When executing `dig +noall +answer <YOUR-CUSTOM-DOMAIN>` yields the 4 IP addresses that you entered in the A records, go back to the Github repository settings and re-enter and save your custom domain name (which you just cleared) in the custom domain cell.
7. Optionally, check the box *Enforce HTTPS*. But make sure that `https://<YOUR-DOMAIN>`is responsive first.

   - Make sure you have a CNAME record in your DNS settings also. Host should be `www` and it should point to your `<YOUR-USERNAME>.github.io`.
   - Make sure there is a file in your website repository named `CNAME` containing the name of your custom domain (in my case `ulfaslak.com`).

[Reference](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain/)

Comment: I followed your steps verbatim and yet when I get to step 7, the checkbox does not become enabled. It states next to the disabled checkbox that I should wait 24 hours for a certificate to be issued. Maybe this case would be helpful to add to your steps?

Comment: My answer is two years old, so maybe this has changed. You're welcome to add it.

Comment: Updated the comment, oddly enough it ended up taking 3 days for my site to work with https.

Comment: worked like a charm after removing A records that are not applicable

Answer (score 5):

Custom domains on GitHub Pages gain support for HTTPS since May 01, 2018

https://blog.github.com/2018-05-01-github-pages-custom-domains-https/